# Need to use a button to open another JFrame, but the JFrame is in other components

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jbutton

I am a Gr12 student working on a project, I made a new JFrame and my other JFrames must be stored in "Other Components." I have seen many tutorials for how to open a new JFrame with a button and I know how to, but this does not work if the other JFrame is stored in "Other Components." Please help!

Comment: Consider adding a snippet of your code

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)